# Moving from one screen to another generates a RecursionError

Tags: python, kivy

I want create an app with a button that will call the another app or another part of this app.

For example:

I'm on the Main screen where I can choose some options like View Report, Create Report, Manage Report, etc. I think that all of those is a app.

So, I make two subclasses from the `App` class of Kivy, each of which has its own `.kv` file. Suppose that one is the Main screen and the another is the another screen.

When I do that it looks like it works, but when I call the second screen, in the console I get the following error in the console:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

How can I fix this?

My `Main.py` file contains

```
from kivy.app import App


class ProbandoApp(App):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    probando = ProbandoApp()

print(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and I have the `.kv` file for each class.

I also have a file called `test.kv` that contains:

```
Widget:
    Button:
        id: btnTest
        text: 'Test'
        width: 100
        height: self.font_size * 2
        on_press: app.probando.run()
```

and a file called `probando.kv` that contains

```
Widget:
    Button:
        id: btnProbando
        text: 'Otra cosa mas para probar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want multiple apps, but a single app whose interface changes. You can do this by switching widgets around, and the [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) provides a convenient api for this.